# Kotlin, RecyclerView, ViewBinding

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewbinding

I'm new to the Kotlin programming language. I have some questions regarding RecyclerView and ViewBinding. My English might not be good. I am sorry for that. But I will do my best to explain. I would love it if you could answer my questions. Please read the questions, looking the images

1.) We give the view to the constructor of the LandmarkHolder class. But when we send this view to the constructor of the RecyclerView.ViewHolder class, we make binding.root.

a) As far as I know, I need to write the object of RecyclerViewRowBinding (which I wrote as binding) in the constructor of Recycler.ViewHolder "in the same way" and send it there. But why do I have to write binding.root instead of "binding"? Why can't I just type "binding"? Because binding already has the design itself.

2.) While making a Layout Inflater, we normally access the XML file with the old method (R.layout. ....) and inflate it, that is, convert it to java code. The structure here has changed. Of course, it is converted to java code again, but there is a confused situation that I could not solve:

A class of the recycler_row.xml file is created called RecyclerRowBinding.

This class has an inflate method. I read from its website. In addition, this class directly references the ids of the views in the layout that are related to it. Now the thing that's stuck in my head is this: What am I inflating here? Because in the old usage (with finviewbyid), when we wrote the inflate method, we were adding a source xml file inside the iflate method.(Like CardView) But this new method does not have it. After the parent is written, attachtoParent is written as False.

3.)What we call this parent represents my RecyclerView?

4.) The holder object in the onBindViewHolder function belongs to the Landmarkholder class. So it uses properties of this class. But I see that it can access something called itemView. Here is how ItemView can relate to the Landmarkholder class. But I'm looking at the class itself, nothing related to this itemView is defined. How does this reach the itemView? Of course, the purpose of calling itemview is to call context. If the context exists in it, then the itemview also derives from another class. Does it derive from the View class? and the View class has this context I guess is it right? How can I call this itemView with "holder" object?

5.) This onCreateViewHolder returns the LandmarkHolder(binding) object. Then this function needs to be called elsewhere for it to work. (Normally it should be called, of course) Butwhere is it called from? On the emulator itself?

[RecyclerViewAdapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XNTi.png)[Recycler_row.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrQGa.png)[MainActivity.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djxvv.png)

[Why isn't the binding itself a view?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj8v2.png)

Comment: Please post the actual text of your code instead of pictures of code. It makes it easier to read and for people that answer you to be able to copy-paste it, and for the question to turn up in search results.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand all your questions, but maybe this overview will help.

ViewBinding takes each of your XML layouts and creates a binding class for them that is comprised of properties matching each view that has an ID, plus one more property named `root` that holds the top-level view. It also has static functions called `bind` and `inflate`. So if you have a layout like this:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerRowTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#0820aa"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then it creates a class that's the equivalent of this (in Java but I'll show a Kotlin version since that's what you're learning):

```
class RecyclerRowBinding private constructor(
    val root: LinearLayout,
    val recyclerRowTextView: TextView
) {
    companion object {
        fun bind(view: View): RecyclerRowBinding {
            val root = view as LinearLayout
            val recyclerRowTextView = root.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recyclerRowTextView)
            return RecyclerRowBinding(root, recyclerRowTextView)
        }

        fun inflate(layoutInflater: LayoutInflater): RecyclerRowBinding {
            return inflate(layoutInflater, null, false)
        }

        fun inflate(layoutInflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup?, attachToParent: Boolean): RecyclerRowBinding {
            val root = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, attachToParent)
            return bind(root)
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't exactly understand your questions, but a couple things to notice:

- It's still inflating your views from XML with a LayoutInflater like you would if you were doing it without view binding.
- The binding itself is not a view class. It only holds references to views.

The RecyclerView.ViewHolder abstract class's constructor requires an `itemView` object, which is the root view of the item layout, so you must pass `binding.root` to this constructor. The binding itself is not the view. RecyclerView.ViewHolder also has a property for this `itemView`, so when you create your own view holder that has a binding, there are two different ways to access the root view, either by using `holder.binding.root` or `holder.itemView`. However, `binding.root` will be of type LinearLayout, and `itemView` will be the less specific `ViewGroup`.

`Adapter.onCreateViewHolder()` is called by RecyclerView when it needs another view to display and doesn't have any previous views that it can recycle.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I added another image. There is a question in the image. I would be very happy if you answer.

Comment: And How can you open RecyclerRowBinding class? I click on it by pressing ctrl but it directs me to the xml file of this class.

Comment: Regarding your question in the image, the binding class cannot both be a view and your specific binding. For example, the root of your layout is the LinearLayout class. The binding is a class that holds references to your specific views so it cannot be an instance of LinearLayout. Also, the binding class can be bound to instances of your layout that have already been created. They don’t mean for you to inspect the binging class, but you can find it if you search through the `generated` directory of your project after building it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was hard for me to understand it but you helped me, thanks a lot